# Why does overriding OnApplyTemplate() in a subclassed Button control give access violation error?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I've come across this problem dealing with subclassing the Windows.UI.Xaml.Button class in C++/CX, and I'd like to know what's going on.

If I subclass the Button control, and add an instance of the subclass to a grid, everything works as expected.

If add an *override method of OnApplyTemplate()* to the subclass, I get NULL-pointerexception when adding the subclass instance to the grid.

My code looks roughly like this (LayoutRoot is a Grid in MainPage.xaml, this sample has been tested in an empty simple metro application):

```
// Scenario 1: This works
LayoutRoot->Children->Append(ref new MyButton1());

// Scenario 2: This doesn't work, it will cause a NULL-pointer exception
LayoutRoot->Children->Append(ref new MyButton2());

// This is how MyButton1 and MyButton2 is defined
public ref class MyButton1 : public Button { 
  public:
    MyButton1() {};
    ~MyButton1() {};
};

public ref class MyButton2 : public Button { 
  public:
    MyButton2() {};
    ~MyButton2() {};
    virtual void OnApplyTemplate() override {};
};
```

**Note that this question is slightly similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287348/why-does-adding-2nd-level-subclassed-button-controls-to-a-grid-give-e-invalidarg), but the error and the scenario is sufficiently different for me to post this one separately.**

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

With the Consumer Preview/Visual Studio 11 Beta, this problem has gone away. The **OnApplyTemplate()** method is virtual, and the OnApplyTemplateCore() method is gone. It took me a while to figure it out, as I got pretty weird compiler errors because of my implementation of the now gone virtual method.

---

**Old answer, applies to the *Developer Preview*:**

The answer makes me feel ashamed for not reading the documentation properly:

The **OnApplyTemplate()** method is *not virtual*, so we *can't* override it. 
The problem is solved by using the overridable **OnUpdateTemplateCore()** method instead.

For some reason it worked for me up until a certain point anyway (and the compiler certainly didn't have anything to say about it), but **overriding it is absolutely not the right thing to do**.